# How to push back a vector into a map<int, vector<int>>

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

What I want to do here is to create a map like this:

```
0 -> 0,1,...,4;
1-> 0,1,...,4;
...
9 -> 0,1,...,4;
```

```cpp
int main(){
    map<int, vector<int>> m;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        vector<int> temp;
        for(int j=0; j<5; i++){
            temp.push_back(j);
        }
        m.insert({i, m.push_back(temp)});
    }
}
```

But when I try to push back `temp = {0,1,2,3,4}` vector, it's giving me an error.

I guess there is some problem in the syntax of the underlined line.

Can you tell me how to solve this error?

[image: Screenshot of the code]

Comment: Please don't tag spam. This is clearly not python. It's not C either - C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: `std::map` doesn't have a `push_back()` function?

Comment: `m.insert({i, m.push_back(temp)});` -> `m.insert({i, temp});`

Comment: Also, you have a typo in the second for-loop, it should be `for(int j=0; j<5; j++)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::map` does not have a `push_back()` method.  You need to insert the `vector` itself that you prepared, eg:

```cpp
int main(){
    map<int, vector<int>> m;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        vector<int> temp;
        for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
            temp.push_back(j);
        }
        m.insert({i, temp});
    }
}
```

Alternatively, use `map::operator[]` instead of `map::insert()`, let the `map` create each `vector` for you, eg:

```cpp
int main(){
    map<int, vector<int>> m;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        vector<int> &vec = m[i];
        for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
            vec.push_back(j);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Note: `for(int j=0; j<5; i++){` - Here `i++` should be `j++`, so to fix it:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>

int main(){
    std::map<int, std::vector<int>> m;

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        std::vector<int> temp;

        for(int j=0; j<5; j++) { // not i++
            temp.push_back(j);
        }

        m.insert({i, temp}); // not  m.insert({i, m.push_back(temp)});
    }
}
```

You could however create *one* `vector<int>` that you copy into the `map`:

```
#include <map>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main(){
    std::vector<int> tmp(5);
    
    std::iota(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), 0); // 0,1,2,3,4

    std::map<int, std::vector<int>> m;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        m.emplace(i, tmp);
    }
}
```